# How to get REST end-point to accept multiple query parameters with the same key?

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have a simple, example REST end-point:

```
component
  restpath = "checkboxes"
  rest     = true
{
  remote void function get(
    string value restargsource = "query" default=""
  )
    httpmethod  = "GET"
    restpath    = ""
    produces    = "application/json"
  {
    restSetResponse( {
      "status" = 200,
      "content" = SerializeJSON( ListToArray( value, ',' ) )
    } );
  }
}
```

If I call it from a simple HTML page:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/rest/checkboxes/" method="GET">
    <label><input name="value" type="checkbox" value="a" /> a</label><br />
    <label><input name="value" type="checkbox" value="b" /> b</label><br />
    <label><input name="value" type="checkbox" value="c" /> c</label><br />
    <label><input name="value" type="checkbox" value="d" /> d</label><br />
    <label><input name="value" type="checkbox" value="e" /> e</label><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the HTTP GET request has a URI like:

```
http://localhost/rest/checkboxes/?value=b&value=e
```

Where there are multiple key-value pairs with the same key.

However, the output from the component is just:

```
["b"]
```

The second and any subsequent values for the same key are omitted.

How can I get all the values for the key?

Answer (score 3):

Either use the `URL` scope (parameters with duplicate keys are represented as a comma-separated string):

```
component
  restpath = "checkboxes"
  rest     = true
{
  remote void function checkboxes(
    string value restargsource = "query" default=""
  )
    httpmethod  = "GET"
    restpath    = ""
    produces    = "application/json"
  {
    var v = [];
    if ( StructKeyExists( URL, "value" ) )
    {
      v = ListToArray( URL.value, ',' );
    }

    restSetResponse( {
      "status" = 200,
      "content" = SerializeJson( v )
    } );
  }
}
```

Or `getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap()[key]` (parameters with duplicate keys are represented as an array of strings):

```
component
  restpath = "checkboxes"
  rest     = true
{
  remote void function checkboxes(
    string value restargsource = "query" default=""
  )
    httpmethod  = "GET"
    restpath    = ""
    produces    = "application/json"
  {
    var v = [];
    var params = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap();
    if ( StructKeyExists( params, "value" ) )
    {
      v = params["value"];
    }

    restSetResponse( {
      "status" = 200,
      "content" = SerializeJson( v )
    } );
  }
}
```